# Xamarin.Forms: Is it possible to dynamically add rows to a grid without the ViewModel calling into the VIew?

Tags: mvvm, xamarin.forms

On a page where I am displaying a receipt to a user, I have a section which lists the subtotal, any taxes, and the total. Since the taxes applicable vary by region and based on the products being sold, the number of rows in this section will vary. For example, here are 3 separate orders, one with GST and PST, one with just GST, and one with neither:

[image: GST+PST]

[image: GST Only]

[image: No Tax]

I've accomplished this by putting just the SubTotal in the grid in XAML, and adding the rest in the code-behind in a method I call from the ViewModel. However, I'd really like to avoid doing it this way, so I'm wondering if there is an approach to accomplishing this which doesn't require having the ViewModel know about the View.

A `ListView` is not suitable here for a number of reasons:

- These controls are inside of a `ScrollView`, and having a `ListView` inside of a `ScrollView` causes all sorts of weird problems.
- I would like to keep the columns as narrow as their widest element. This is possible with a `Grid`, but a `ListView` would take up the entire width of its parent no matter what.
- I neither need nor want for my rows to be selectable

So is there a way I can do this without the ViewModel knowing about the View *and* without resorting to using a `ListView`?

Comment: you can do it from code, but why does it have to be the VM and not the View's code-behind?  Doing it in the VM would badly break MVVM.  Why can't the View's code behind just update based on the number of rows in the VM?

Comment: Hm, I realize now I both worded the question badly and was thinking about it the wrong way. What I want to do is not add the rows from the ViewModel, but be able to add the rows without having the ViewModel know about the View. But now that I look at it this way, the solution is obvious, so thank you very much!

Comment: Can't you just create Auto sized rows for the GST and PST and hide them is they are not required? p.s. nice to see you using FreshMvvm!

Comment: @SteveChadbourne the problem is then what happens when the app is used in a province that has HST, or in a state with sales tax, or in the euro zone where VAT applies, or when a new tax is introduced... having a list of all possible taxes hard-coded in the UI seems unfeasible and unmaintainable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to encapsulate the functionality you require so that the view and the view model are not coupled is by creating a user control.

I created a new user control called TotalsGridControl. Here is the XAML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Grid xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="ScratchPad.UserControls.TotalsGridControl"
             x:Name="TotalsGrid">

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

</Grid>
```

And here is the code behind.

```
public partial class TotalsGridControl : Grid
{
    public TotalsGridControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty TotalsProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Totals), typeof(List<TotalItem>), typeof(TotalsGridControl), null,
            BindingMode.OneWay, null, OnTotalsChanged);

    private static void OnTotalsChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldvalue, object newvalue)
    {
        var control = (TotalsGridControl)bindable;
        if (control != null)
        {
            if (newvalue is List<TotalItem> totals)
            {
                var rowNumber = -1;
                double grandTotal = 0;

                foreach (var totalItem in totals)
                {
                    grandTotal += totalItem.Value;

                    var descLabel = new Label {Text = totalItem.Description};
                    var valueLabel = new Label { Text = totalItem.Value.ToString("c") };

                    rowNumber++;
                    control.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto});
                    control.Children.Add(descLabel, 0, rowNumber);
                    control.Children.Add(valueLabel, 1, rowNumber);
                }

                var grandTotalDescLabel = new Label { Text = "Total" };
                var grandTotalValueLabel = new Label { Text = grandTotal.ToString("c") };

                rowNumber++;
                control.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto });
                control.Children.Add(grandTotalDescLabel, 0, rowNumber);
                control.Children.Add(grandTotalValueLabel, 1, rowNumber);
            }
        }
    }

    public List<TotalItem> Totals
    {
        get => (List<TotalItem>)GetValue(TotalsProperty);
        set => SetValue(TotalsProperty, value);
    }
}
```

I used a bindable property to allow a list of TotalItem to be bound to the user control.

Here is the data in the view model

```
public List<TotalItem> Totals { get; set; }

Totals = new List<TotalItem>
{
    new TotalItem {Description = "SubTotal", Value = 99.91},
    new TotalItem {Description = "GST", Value = 5.0},
    new TotalItem {Description = "PST", Value = 4.9}
};
```

and here is the XAML in the page

```
<userControls:TotalsGridControl Totals="{Binding Totals}"/>
```

And the output

[image]

Comment: Could be help how can i put this inside the listview, right now if i am using this inside my list view the labels are added to every listview group for its corresponding row

Answer (score 0):

Before:

```
public class ReceiptPageModel : PageModelBase
{
    private Receipt _receipt;
    public Receipt Receipt
    {
        get => _receipt;
        private set => Set(ref _receipt, value);
    }

    public override void Init(object initData)
    {
        Receipt = (Receipt) initData;
        ((ReceiptPage) CurrentPage).AddTaxes(Receipt);
    }
}
```

After:

```
public class ReceiptPageModel : PageModelBase
{
    private Receipt _receipt;
    public Receipt Receipt
    {
        get => _receipt;
        private set => Set(ref _receipt, value);
    }

    public override void Init(object initData)
    {
        Receipt = (Receipt) initData;
    }
}

public partial class ReceiptPage : FreshBaseContentPage
{
    public ReceiptPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContextChanged += HandlePageModelAdded;
    }

    private void HandlePageModelAdded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var pageModel = (ReceiptPageModel)BindingContext;
        if (pageModel.Receipt != null)
        {
            AddTaxes(pageModel.Receipt);
        }
        else
        {
            pageModel.PropertyChanged += (s, args) =>
            {
                if (args.PropertyName == nameof(pageModel.Receipt))
                    AddTaxes(pageModel.Receipt);
            };
        }
    }

    private void AddTaxes(Receipt receipt)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This is still coupling the page and page model. One should not know about the other.

Comment: @SteveChadbourne how would you reconcile this then? Is there a way I can accomplish this without either one knowing about the other?

Comment: I added an answer showing how to use a user control to do this.